# Creating a window that doesnt appear in print screen

Tags: windows, winforms, graphics, directx, gdi

When press print screen on windows, the mouse cursor doesnt show up in screenshot. Wondering how is it created, with what attributes.  I couldnt find the Hwnd of Mouse cursor using SPY++ and other tools.

I wanted to create a window that doesnt appear in the prting screen. screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor does not appears because it is a legacy hardware feature, your computer could freeze that the cursor still move.

As for blocking screenshot, if you create a direct x swap chain, you have protection flags for that purpose. I don't know for regular hwnd tho.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, the mouse cursor was a special part of hardware that created an overlay and wasn't actually rendered into the same video memory as the rest of the screen.  Even today, it's not a window (in the user32 sense of a window)--it doesn't have an HWND.  It may still be special enough that it's not part of the rendering, or it may be that the Print Screen functionality may temporarily hide the cursor when it grabs the screen shot.

I don't think there's a simple general purpose way to ensure your window cannot be captured by a screenshot.  Perhaps if your window was owned by a "[high-integrity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx)" process, it might be blanked out of a screenshot captured by a regular- or low-integrity process.  But I've never tried that.